# How to click on dynamically changing id and class selenium java

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Details -**
want to select the dropdown but id and classes are changed. I also tried to select using **selenium** css selector but no result.

see the below image [image]

Want to click on all dropdown one by one but id and classes are **dynamically** changed

**code -**

```
jQuery('.yui3-widget.yui3-c-gizmo.yui3-c-button.yui3-c-button-content.description.btn.btnSilvericon.button-primary.icon-right-dropdown.s-btn-all').eq(1).click()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code in text format here.

Comment: If you wanna click on all just use `document.querySelectorAll('select')`. Else use something which does not change then (extra class, extra attribute, tabindex, ..). As a side question - why would your ids change?

Comment: Why would you want to click on a Dropdown in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following CSS locator:

```
button.description.btnSilvericon[id^='yui'][title='All']
```

Practice CSS Selectors to deal with dynamic elements:

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors

Comment: Note that * is for contains string , since `yui` is always in initials , you can easily replace it by ^ for starting text.

Comment: Modified to use more specific locators by adding class

Answer (score 0):

You can use this path :

`//button[starts-with(@id, 'yui') and @title='All']` or

```
 //span[starts-with(@id, 'yui') and contains(.,'All')]
```

For css :

```
button[id^='yui'][title='All'] or

span[id^='yui']
```

^ = starts with in CSS(Shift + 6)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: using only id matches with multiple elements as there are more than one element having 'id' value starting with 'yui' in the given HTML.

Comment: You are right Naveen. updated answer. Although he can use only span selector for dropdown

Comment: //button[starts-with(@id, 'yui') and @title='All']

Too many titles are having Title = ALL  
in this case what i do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on all drop down elements, it's sufficient that you  use only one class or a combination of few classes that is common to all of them (but only to them). You don't need to specify the random id or class.

If you're using Selenium, use `findElements` to return all the matching elements and then loop on this list to click its elements. Use the `by.class` locator if you want to specify only one class name or `by.cssSelector` to specify a combination of classes prefixed and separated by dots.